# Similarity matrix in D3

Tags: javascript, beginner, d3.js

I have some code that produces a similarity matrix. However, despite feeling happy with the output, I'm not convinced that my code is the most efficient or the most pleasing on the eye.

I'm looking to make it more efficient and tidier, as well as open to advice on what could be implemented to make the end product better.

```
var data = [ 
  [["Arsenal", 0.0], ["Chelsea", 0.6014876082652767], ["Liverpool", 0.5204181171517794],["ManchesterCity", 0.549210189254557], ["ManchesterUnited", 0.5440890632512689], ["Tottenham", 0.6304670189118691]],
  [["Arsenal",0.6014876082652767], ["Chelsea",0.0], ["Liverpool",0.5507313736526684],["ManchesterCity",0.5559069243804156], ["MancheserUnited",0.5231358671618266], ["Tottenham",0.6508134781353688]],
  [["Arsenal",0.5204181171517794], ["Chelsea",0.5507313736526684], ["Liverpool",0.0],["ManchesterCity",0.49759390310994533], ["MancheserUnited",0.4787550034617063], ["Tottenham",0.5749363562907429]],
  [["Arsenal",0.549210189254557], ["Chelsea",0.5559069243804156], ["Liverpool",0.49759390310994533],["ManchesterCity",0.0,], ["MancheserUnited",0.50215325905151], ["Tottenham",0.5802928689025063]],
  [["Arsenal",0.5440890632512689], ["Chelsea",0.5231358671618266], ["Liverpool",0.4787550034617063],["ManchesterCity",0.50215325905151], ["MancheserUnited",0.0], ["Tottenham",0.5497016431211542]],
  [["Arsenal",0.6304670189118691], ["Chelsea",0.6508134781353688], ["Liverpool",0.5749363562907429],["ManchesterCity",0.5802928689025063], ["MancheserUnited",0.5497016431211542], ["Tottenham",0.0]]
];

var teams = ["ARS", "CHE", "LIV", "MCI", "MUN", "TOT"]

var cols = data.length;
var rows = data.length;
var cellSize = 55;

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600 )
    .attr("height", 500)

svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
      return "translate(" + i * cellSize + ")"
    })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {return d;})
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d[1] == 0) {
            return "#2A363B";
        } else if (d[1] <= 0.50) {
            return "#F8B195";
        } else if (d[1] <= 0.55) {
            return "#F67280";
        } else if (d[1] <= 0.59) {
            return "#C06C84";
        } else if (d[1] <= 0.62) {
            return "#6C5B7B";
        } else if (d[1] >= 0.63) {
            return "#355C7D";
        }})
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return i * cellSize ;
    })
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("r", 55);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some advices regarding the D3 part of the code:

#### Use scales!

Your `if... else` logic for filling the rectangles is cumbersome and luckily unnecessary: you can use a scale, in that case a threshold scale:

```
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .range(["#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D"])
    .domain([0.5, 0.55, 0.59, 0.62]);
```

Then, you can do just this in the `attr` method:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d[1] === 0 ? "#2A363B" : color(d[1])
});
```

Do the same for the positions. Right now, you're using a lot of magic numbers everywhere: for translating the groups, positioning the rectangles and setting their width/height.

Instead of that, set up band scales:

```
var horizontalGrid = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([100, 400])
    .domain(d3.range(cols))
    .padding(0.1);

var verticalGrid = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, 300])
    .domain(d3.range(rows))
    .padding(0.1);
```

Using them for translating the groups...

```
.attr("transform", function(_, i) {
    return "translate(" + horizontalGrid(i) + ")"
})
```

...and positioning the rectangles, as well as setting the dimensions:

```
.attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return verticalGrid(i);
})
.attr("width", horizontalGrid.bandwidth())
.attr("height", verticalGrid.bandwidth());
```

Finally, two important advices:

#### Always name your selections

That's very important when the visualisation becomes more and more complex. For instance, you should do:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
    //etc...
```

#### Break your selections

By breaking your selections not only you can easily reference the correct selection, but you can also avoid things (silently) breaking. And it's way easy to maintain. For instance, in your code:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
    //etc...

var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
    //etc...
```

Now you have two selections, `groups` (which refers to the containing `<g>` elements) and rects (which refers to the rectangles).

#### Select nothing

You read it right. If you don't plan to have an update selection here, just select nothing in your enter selections, or for a cleaner code select `null`. So, since you're not selecting anything, you have an enter selection which **always** contains all the data points, and a way faster code.

So, the move snippet becomes:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll(null)
    //etc...

var rects = groups.selectAll(null)
    //etc...
```

If you want to read more about `selectAll(null)` read my explanation here: [Selecting null: what is the reason behind 'selectAll(null)' in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46147231/5768908).

#### Demo

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var data = [
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.0],
    ["Chelsea", 0.6014876082652767],
    ["Liverpool", 0.5204181171517794],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.549210189254557],
    ["ManchesterUnited", 0.5440890632512689],
    ["Tottenham", 0.6304670189118691]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.6014876082652767],
    ["Chelsea", 0.0],
    ["Liverpool", 0.5507313736526684],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.5559069243804156],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.5231358671618266],
    ["Tottenham", 0.6508134781353688]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.5204181171517794],
    ["Chelsea", 0.5507313736526684],
    ["Liverpool", 0.0],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.49759390310994533],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.4787550034617063],
    ["Tottenham", 0.5749363562907429]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.549210189254557],
    ["Chelsea", 0.5559069243804156],
    ["Liverpool", 0.49759390310994533],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.0, ],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.50215325905151],
    ["Tottenham", 0.5802928689025063]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.5440890632512689],
    ["Chelsea", 0.5231358671618266],
    ["Liverpool", 0.4787550034617063],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.50215325905151],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.0],
    ["Tottenham", 0.5497016431211542]
  ],
  [
    ["Arsenal", 0.6304670189118691],
    ["Chelsea", 0.6508134781353688],
    ["Liverpool", 0.5749363562907429],
    ["ManchesterCity", 0.5802928689025063],
    ["MancheserUnited", 0.5497016431211542],
    ["Tottenham", 0.0]
  ]
];

var teams = ["ARS", "CHE", "LIV", "MCI", "MUN", "TOT"];

var width = 600,
  height = 500;

var cols = data.length;
var rows = data.length;
var cellSize = 55;

var horizontalGrid = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([100, 400])
  .domain(d3.range(cols))
  .padding(0.1);

var verticalGrid = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, 300])
  .domain(d3.range(rows))
  .padding(0.1);

var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .range(["#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D"])
  .domain([0.5, 0.55, 0.59, 0.62])

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

var groups = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(_, i) {
    return "translate(" + horizontalGrid(i) + ")"
  });
  
var rects = groups.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d[1] === 0 ? "#2A363B" : color(d[1])
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return verticalGrid(i);
  })
  .attr("width", horizontalGrid.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", verticalGrid.bandwidth());
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Normally I would agree that named instances is favorable, but in this case D3 is specifically designed to facilitate the declarative approch. Quotes from d3js.org "the W3C DOM API is tedious: ... and the imperative approach requires manual iteration and bookkeeping of temporary state." and "D3 employs a declarative approach,..." The last 3 names you introduced just add noise and offer no clarity  Also all variables should be `const` and data that should have been named, remains as  randomly scattered magic numbers.

Comment: @Blindman67 *"The last 3 names you introduced just add noise and offer no clarity"*... This is completely incorrect. Are you familiar with D3? (genuine question, not a rhetorical one) By naming the selection one can easily create an enter/update/exit pattern, adding listeners, setting up transitions etc without re-selecting by class or tag, which would be way slower. That's the idiomatic D3.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid magic

- Avoid littering your code with magic numbers and strings. Keep them in one place and give them meaningful names. This makes it much easier to maintain.

  Visualizations usually go through a tweaking stage to get the look perfect, having the same value in many places, or meaningless numbers make the process tedious, and dangerous (introduce bugs).

  The easier it is to make adjustments the more time you can spend on improving quality, rather than avoid touching it in fear of breaking it.

### Some points about code.

- Use `const` for your constants. There are no variable that you change in the code.
- Use arrow functions to reduce code noise.
- Naming function arguments so that they have meaning in the context that they are used.
- Use a containing object (eg DIV) to hold the resulting content.
- Use the containing element`s` dataset`to define additional properties.
- D3 is not just for SVG, for simple layouts you will get better performance using HTML elements
- Vet your data sources, You had two spellings for `"ManchesterUnited"` and `"MancheserUnited"`

### The rewrite

As an example of the above points, also cleaned up the data, (no need to have anything over 4 decimal points).

Cell size and cell padding is taken from the containing element. Uses viewBox to lock aspect and has resize listener to keep content centered and scaled to fit.

```js
const data =[[["Arsenal", 0.0000], ["Chelsea", 0.6015], ["Liverpool", 0.5204], ["ManchesterCity", 0.5492], ["ManchesterUnited", 0.5441], ["Tottenham", 0.6305], ], [["Arsenal", 0.6015], ["Chelsea", 0.0000], ["Liverpool", 0.5507], ["ManchesterCity", 0.5559], ["ManchesterUnited", 0.5231], ["Tottenham", 0.6508], ], [["Arsenal", 0.5204], ["Chelsea", 0.5507], ["Liverpool", 0.0000], ["ManchesterCity", 0.4976], ["ManchesterUnited", 0.4788], ["Tottenham", 0.5749], ], [["Arsenal", 0.5492], ["Chelsea", 0.5559], ["Liverpool", 0.4976], ["ManchesterCity", 0.0000], ["ManchesterUnited", 0.5022], ["Tottenham", 0.5803], ], [["Arsenal", 0.5441], ["Chelsea", 0.5231], ["Liverpool", 0.4788], ["ManchesterCity", 0.5022], ["ManchesterUnited", 0.0000], ["Tottenham", 0.5497], ], [["Arsenal", 0.6305], ["Chelsea", 0.6508], ["Liverpool", 0.5749], ["ManchesterCity", 0.5803], ["ManchesterUnited", 0.5497], ["Tottenham", 0.0000], ]];
const fills = {
   col : ["#2A363B", "#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D"],
   scale : [0, 0.5, 0.55, 0.59, 0.62, 1],
};

function scaleToFit() { // To scale and fit the page, is also called on resize
    const scaled = Math.min((innerWidth - pagePadding )/ size, (innerHeight - pagePadding ) / size) * size | 0;
    simMatrix.attr("width", scaled).attr("height", scaled);
    container.style.left = (innerWidth - scaled) / 2 + "px";
}

const containerId = "dataDisplay";
const contentId = "simMatrix";
const container = document.getElementById(containerId);
const cellPad = +container.dataset.cellPad;   
const cellSize = +container.dataset.cellSize + cellPad;
const rows = data.length;
const size = rows * cellSize;
const viewBox = `0 0 ${size} ${size}`;  // To maintain aspect when resizing
const position = (data, index) => cellSize * index; 
const pagePadding = 20; // to keep content away from  edges. Divide by 2 for actual dist from edges
const fill = data => fills.col[fills.scale.findIndex(v => data[1] <= v)]; // fill color alternative to using d3.scaleThreshold
addEventListener("resize", scaleToFit); 

d3.select("#" + containerId)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("id", contentId)  
  .attr("viewBox",viewBox)
  .attr("width", size)
  .attr("height", size)
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg") // using SVG rather than g element to simplify column positioning
  .attr("x", position) // use data index to set x position
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data => data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("r", cellSize)
  .attr("width", cellSize - cellPad)
  .attr("height", cellSize - cellPad)
  .attr("y", position)
  .attr("fill", fill);

const simMatrix = d3.select("#" + contentId); 
scaleToFit(); // fit to page
```

```css
.d3Container {
  position : absolute;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="dataDisplay" class="d3Container" data-cell-size="40" data-cell-pad="4"></div>
```